# Git - How to squash commits after they have been marged into master

Tags: git

I was working on a new feature on my local branch, I made some commits and then I create the merge request. It has been validated and merged into master, other merge requests have been pushed after that.

The issue is that we have multiple commits visible in the master branch with WIP and wrong ticket reference. I want to squash these commits in one and set the commit message.

We have the following commits on master:

**EDIT**

```
 git log --graph --oneline master
* 63bcd68ce (HEAD -> master) [maven-release-plugin] prepare for next development iteration
* 625d40a55 (tag: pta-root-3.6.1) [maven-release-plugin] prepare release pta-root-3.6.1
* 16b304566 (pta_temp) PTAP-XXXX - WIP Authentication anonymous updates
* d5bf94fdc PTAP-XXXX - checkstyle issues
* 76f5107bc PTAP-XXXX - WIP Authentication anonymous
* ef7c71eb5 PTAP-XXXX - WIP Authentication anonymous
* 21d9271d8 PTAP-XXXX - WIP Authentication anonymous
* aa0af50da PTAP-XXXX - WIP Authentication anonymous-2
* e0b964795 PTAP-XXXX - WIP Authentication anonymous
* 96984a70c PTAP-XXXX - WIP Authentication part 2
* 7832f7911 PTAP-XXXX - WIP Authentication
* 040db7d97 [maven-release-plugin] prepare for next development iteration
```

Is there any way to make it like this:

```
* 63bcd68ce (HEAD -> master) [maven-release-plugin] prepare for next development iteration
* 625d40a55 (tag: pta-root-3.6.1) [maven-release-plugin] prepare release pta-root-3.6.1
* xxxxxxx PTAP-330- Add anonymous authentication 
* 040db7d97 [maven-release-plugin] prepare for next development iteration
```

Comment: There is.... but it requires rewriting history of master branch. You should use `git log --graph --one-line master` so that we can see how the revisions are laid out to tell you the details.

Comment: If the revisions are laid out in a straight line (no merges) then you could run `git rebase -i f325c30`, pick the first revision from your commits and squash the others, then pick d258546 and 1bd2200. Those revisions will all be listed when you run `git rebase -i`.

Comment: Your goal situation is impossible to achieve since `d258546` has `0f1efa9` for its parent forever. However, as eftshoft0 suggested, you could rebase the branch to make new commits with the same content, but they won't have the same hash. If the branch is shared (which seems likely reading your question) you'll mess people's local histories by force-pushing your rebased branch. Be **sure** to communicate with your woworkers on this before every actual change on the remote.

Comment: But be warned, this is VERY RISKY. Every other copy of this repo will need to be manually updated to the new location for the master branch, or you run the risk of someone merging the old branch into the new branch, resurrecting your commits anyway. Or a system no longer being able to pull because of the moved branch.

Comment: @Mikezx6r I'm aware of that and there is no risk since I'm the only developer on the project.

Comment: Good. Also want to make sure others that find this question are aware of the risks involved.